# Can I use 'not' and 'contains' filter together in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I want to apply 'not' and 'contains' filter together to filter element in HTML.

consider I have element as follows ,

```
<tr class="filter" value="value1" name="something1">
<tr class="filter" value="value1" name="something2">
<tr class="filter" value="value3" name="something3">
<tr class="filter" value="value1" name="something4">
```

and I want to apply filter as

```
$(".filter").not("[value*='value1']").contains('something4')
```

But it does not work.
Please help me, Thanks.

Comment: can you tell us what exactly you are targeting? as per code you have written seems impossible to return the target element.

Comment: I want to apply class to those element whose value is not equal to 'value1' and name is equal to something4

Comment: so in the above trs which one  is your target?

Comment: 4'th one is my target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `.filter()` method instead:

```
var filtered = $(".filter").filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('value') !== 'value1' && $(this).attr('name') === 'something4'
});
filtered.css('color', 'red');
```

with attribute selectors *(Not recommended)*:

```
$(".filter:not([value*='value1']):contains('something4')")
```

---

As per your comment:

*4'th one is my target*

Then:

You don't have to check for negative values but you should go for the equality:

```
var filtered = $(".filter").filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('value') === 'value1' && $(this).attr('name') === 'something4'
});
filtered.css('color', 'red');
```

or:

```
$(".filter[value='value1'][name='something4']").css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: Thanks for help Jai, Can I do it without filter function.

Comment: yes! but `.filter()` method is quite performant although you can use attribute selectors.

Comment: If yes then please give me that approach also.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single selector, however performance will be better using `filter()` as noted in Jai`s answer.

```
$(".filter:not([value*='value1']):contains('something4')")
```

Also note that given your HTML example, this selector will not match anything as you exclude the element with the `something4` text with the `:not`.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, aren't the jQuery pseudo selectors, like `:not` and `:contains` considered to be less performant than `.not()` and `.contains()` methods?

Comment: In modern versions of jQuery, yes. However @Jai already posted that answer :)

Comment: Thanks Rory it gives error as 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined'

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan seems `:not` has missing `()`.